# Android: App working on WiFi but neither on 3G nor 2G

Tags: java, android

I desperately need help with this problem. I know there are already questions on these lines but none of them are quite like the issue I'm facing at the moment.

I have an app which pulls the follow JSON data from a URL:

```
{
  "dateToday" = "17th May" 
}
```

The code to retrieve that data is as follows:

```
        protected List<String> doInBackground(List<String>... arg0) {

        Log.d("Refresh Check","In background...");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<String> matchDetails = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            Log.d("Refresh Check","In try...");
            json = jsonData.retrieveData(URL, client);
            Log.d("Refresh Check",json.toString());
            String date = json.getString("dateToday");
            matchDetails.add(date);
            return matchDetails;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Arrays.asList("Connectivity issue");
    }
```

And the retrieve data function is:

```
public JSONObject retrieveData(String URL, HttpClient client)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {

    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
    int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (status == 200) {
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        JSONObject last = new JSONObject(data);
        return last;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So when I run this on my phone using WiFi, everything works and gets updated perfectly but when I switch to my data plan on 3G or 2G, the data just doesn't refresh at all.

The 3rd Log.d in my code, which checks for the String, keeps returning the date as 17th May even if I change the JSON value to 18th.

The only difference in the logcat I could note for WiFi versus my data plan was that the data plan had an error on the lines of **Network Controller: iconLevel >= 5**

Here's where it gets annoying though, there are times when the app works completely fine even on 2G, it's like it won't work for a while, then say I switch from 2G to WiFi and then back to 2G, it works. The behaviour of the app has been very erratic.

Things I've tried so far:

1.) Use another phone to see if the issue persists (it did).

2.) Check if my phone browser could access the URL and display the updated results (it could).

So I am now clueless as hell and really close to giving up on the app after 3 weeks of unexplained execution.

If anyone could help, I'd be very very very grateful. **This is what I have now narrowed to:**

1.) Why precisely would getting light-weight data from a particular URL behave differently on WiFi and on 3G/2G

2.) Is android saving the data to cache or something? Because every time I start the app, it should reach the doInBackground wherein, it should retrieve the updated data from the site but the log simply shows the old data.

3.) Would it help if I tried loading the apk separately onto my device rather than running it on my phone through eclipse? I mean, is there any difference between the two?

Any help would be extremely appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When exactly are you retrieving this data? Are you using `onDataConnectionStateChanged` to go and retrieve the data again?

Comment: Oh no. I have a refresh button which calls the Async Task. Other than that, I also have a timely refresh using handlers. 
this.myHandler = new Handler();
  this.myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, refreshTime);

Comment: Perhaps your refresh is not doing what you assume.

Comment: It is on WiFi though. Additionally, the Log.d I've used, does show me that the code is going into the AsyncTask everytime I hit refresh but it just brings back stale data most of the times but randomly, it even works perfectly at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for the delay in getting back about this.

Darkangle's suggestion seems to be spot on.

However, I had checked through the cache issue on stackoverflow and found a solution which worked well for me.

This was the change to the code:

```
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
    get.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
    get.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
```

The get.setHeaders which made sure new data is fetched every time.

Thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 3):

it's probably the caching when you request json data from server.

You can try to add a `timestamp` string behind your url when you requesting data from server to ensure ever request is a new request to avoid caching

for example :

Original Url : `mytest.com/webservice/?date=today`

add extra parameter :  `mytest.com/webservice/?date=today&timestamp=ddmmyyhhmmss`

Answer (score 1):

You obviously have a cache problem here. As everything is running fine on wifi, I think the issue probably comes from a cache in your network provider infrastructure. Your request is a GET, it could easily get cached by any element on the path. to work around this you can

- configure the HTTP server to add a cache control headers (header `Cache-Control` with `no-cache` or `max-age` or header `expire` ) to the answer to your request (how to do this depends on the http server you use). Actually, it can be a bit more tricky than that, see this [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers#Avoiding_caching) on wikipedia avoid avoiding caching.
- add a random parameter to your url (as suggested by @Darkangle)